# Only 1 record is shown in page Crystal Report

Tags: c#-4.0, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

Descriptors Column:(From Database)

ID   Descriptors

1     Viewing

2     Listening

3     Teaching

When its retrieve it only display the first record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't comment as it requires 50 reputation and I have only 19,lol
but you need to be more descriptive in your question and should write your code and picture of crystal report output.

but understanding your question I can say that you should write these columns in detail section and don't expand the hight of section, keep the height as much as your fields are.

Comment: yes, you are quiet right, I am also sure that he has pasted the fields in the header section, while you should be putting them in details section, or maybe the query he is calling is retrieving just one record.

Comment: share it somewhere else, and please edit your question and put the code snippet about the call to the report, and the selection formula or query that you pass! the question is ambiguous.